# how to enable a check box using stored values in a file like arrays

Tags: php, html

hiii,
i have a check box ,while submitting the form i will store the check box value like 1 or 0 ,if i reload the page then checked value not showing so i want retrieve from file .if i refresh or navigate to back it should maintan the state.
i have tried this,but not working

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enable" name="check[0]" value="1" checked='<?php echo ($arr[3]==1 ? 'true' : 'false');?>' />
```

please help me with this
thanks..

Comment: When the form is submitted as POST, then you will find `$_POST['check'][0]` with the value 'on', when it was checked. Do not use a value on checkboxes! You need to adapt this in the checked attribute. Setting the string true or false is wrong. Just place `checked` when it should be checked. Otherwise leave it away.

Comment: Try this `<input type="checkbox" id="enable" name="check[0]" value="1"<?php echo ($arr[3] == 1 ? ' checked' : ''); ?>' />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo `checked` if enabled:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enable" name="check[0]" value="1" <?php echo $arr[3]==1 ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
```